# MySQLdb import works from command line but crashes in PyCharm

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, virtualenv, python-import, mysql-python

I am using a Python 2.7 virtualenv with the MySQLdb package installed.
If I run Python from the *command line* and execute `import MySQLdb`, this works without error. If I run it from the *PyCharm terminal*, however, I get an error:

```
ImportError: libmysqlclient.so.20: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The same pattern occurs if I execute a file `test.py` containing the line `import MySQLdb`. It works when executed from the command line and crashed when executed from PyCharm.

I have googled the error and it seems that uninstalling and reinstalling MySQLdb could fix it. But I would like to understand **why** the error only occurs in PyCharm.
I have made sure that both the command line and the PyCharm terminal use

- the same virtual environment (by checking `sys.executable`)
- the same working directory (by checking `os.getcwd()`)
- the same path (by checking `sys.path`)

I have also checked that `PYTHONPATH` is undefined.
What other difference could there be?

Answer (score 0):

You have to point pycharm to your virtualenv.  Go to settings -> project interpreter and give pycharm the path to your python executable.  Once there it should work.  Note if you have a hybrid WSL/windows setup you will need one virtualenv for WSL and a separate virtualenv for windows/pycharm.